# Set Academic year from date picker to textbox

Tags: c#

Dear all genius kindly help me, I am beginner in C# windows application: In my current school project I want to set an academic year. From the datepicker start and end date of the academic year could be picked and in the textbox the starting year and the last two digit of the end year should be shown.
Below is the picture example:

[image]

I had been looking all over google from past weeks but could not get any, please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it *winform* or *WPF*?

Comment: *ANYWAYS* Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Thanks all for trying.
Here I solved this:

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String str = dateTimePicker2.Value.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2);
        textBox1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.Year.ToString() + "-" + str;
    }

    private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String str = dateTimePicker2.Value.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2);
        textBox1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.Year.ToString() + "-" + str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use strings for dates if at all possible. No exceptions.

You only need to select the start date. Here it is fixed, but you would use the date from the date picker:

```
DateTime yearFrom = new DateTime(2015, 12, 26);
DateTime yearTo = yearFrom.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);

string academicYear = yearFrom.Year.ToString() + yearTo.ToString("'-'yy"); 

// academicYear -> 2015-16
```

Comment: Dear @ Gustav, thanks for the reply. I'll look into it and let you know.

Comment: Dear @  Alex, its a window form. I am working with C#

Comment: Dear @ Gustav, I am following your instruction but don't find any results. Please help and look into this code:                               private void test2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime yearFrom = new DateTime(2015, 12, 26);
            DateTime yearTo = yearFrom.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);

            string academicYear = yearFrom.Year.ToString() + yearTo.ToString("'-'yy"); 

        }

Comment: Mr. Gustav I am using your code in page load event, please need your guide for your code. Thanks a ton.

Comment: The code creates the string and assigns it to `academicYear`. Then you should assign that to your textbox "Academic Year".

Comment: @ Mr. Gustav, here is my code :                                                                      private void test2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime yearFrom = new DateTime(2015, 12, 26);
            DateTime yearTo = yearFrom.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);


            string academicYear = yearFrom.Year.ToString() + yearTo.ToString("'-'yy");
            textBox1.Text = academicYear;

        }

Comment: @ Mr. Gustav, no matter which ever year or date I pick from yearFrom datepicker and yearTo picker I always get the result in my textbox as 2015-16. I don't get why is this 2015 hard coded and 16 no idea from where it is coming. I want both year in the textbox should come from datepicker yearFrom and datepicker yearTo.  really need help with this, kindly look into it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DateTime(2015, 12, 26)`is hardcoded in the code. You can't see that? Really? Replace that with the date value from your datepicker.